# Downloading files with multiple extensions on a webpage using mechanize library in Python

Tags: python, mechanize, urllib

My first question on Stack Overflow!

I'm trying to download resumes of a job posting website. I've found the link that leads to the download, but those downloads have a '.php' ending, and hence I don't know the extension of the file that is going be downloaded (.doc, .docx, .pdf)The relevant last section of the link looks this: ("~/resumedownload.php?f=WFeilbBZWg==")

I'm logging into the website with mechanize. I've used mechanize to login the website, and this what I do to download the file:

```
filename = br.retrieve(link.get('href'),
os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Job Postings/Hirist/" + str(i) +
".pdf"))[0]
```

, but this only brings back the .pdf files and corrupts the rest. The filename variable is a .php file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`Browser.retrieve()` returns a tuple consisting of the filename to which the file was written and the headers from the remote server. You can then use the `Content-Type` header to determine the MIME type of the file and the [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension) module to get an appropriate extension for the file. Finally, rename the file.

```
import mechanize
import shutil
import os.path
import mimetypes

#url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
url = 'http://heriverde.nimoz.pl/wp-content/uploads/pdf-sample.pdf'
br = mechanize.Browser()
filename, headers = br.retrieve(url)

dest_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Job Postings/Hirist/')
# Content-Type may include encoding, e.g. text/html; charset=utf-8
content_type = headers.get('Content-Type', '').split(';')[0]
extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)
if not extension:
    extension = '.dunno'

# `i` is assumed to be a counter
dest_filename = '{}{}'.format(i, extension)
shutil.move(filename, os.path.join(dest_dir, dest_filename))
```